# "How to NOT create own company. Case study." Is it a correct title for presentation?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, speech

I want to create a presentation, in which I will tell people about my mistakes which I made, when I started my own company.

I have a difficulty with defining a title in English :( I have a gut feeling, that this title do not represent what I want to tell people. And I want to say:

- those are my mistakes, do not do that
- this and that should be done in different order
- avoid doing this, etc...

But I *don't* want to say:

- do not create own company

To be honest, presentation will tell something completely opposite. Small help from native speakers would be for sure tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 6):

***How NOT to create your own company*** sounds better to my ears.

Comment: Agreed.  "How NOT to create" discusses the wrong way to go about things.  "How to NOT create" would discuss the steps to take to avoid creating something.

Comment: Also I would re-punctuate the bit about the case study: "How NOT to create your own company: a case study" sounds much better than any alternatives to me.